# Elasticsearch Error: Could not evaluate jvm.options

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, jvm

So I've been trying to setup Elasticsearch using Windows for the past half a day, and after going through errors and errors, I reached an error that occurs when I try to run the program by typing in elasticsearch.exe in the command prompt, or clicking on the desktop/file explorer shortcut for Elasticsearch. I don't know how to fix this error, nor could I find a solution online. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but get the same problem. The error is as follows:

[image: elasticsearch error]

Can anyone provide some help on how to fix this? Been trying and searching for hours but nada. I have my Paths setup correctly as shown here:

[image: paths]

Thank you.

Comment: You're using Java 15, while the latest supported release is Java 11. Did the ElasticSearch  download require Java 15 specifically? You might find using 11 will help. I suspect the error may be due to the `c:\ProgramData` path -- have you checked that exists?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the problem is that the "config" folder in your case placed at the different address.
In my case the same problem was solved by moving "Elastic" folder (with all its content) from the "C:\Program Files" folder  directly to the disc "C:". In this case the "config\jvm.options" folder\file appeared directly in the "Elastic" folder. After that update the nesessary pathes: the "ES_HOME", the "ES_PATH_CONF" and created a "ES_JAVA_HOME" path as well since this is a specific path that ElasticSearch (ES) will use. In my case all pathes looked like that:

ES_HOME        C:\elasticsearch-7.16.2
ES_PATH_CONF   C:\elasticsearch-7.16.2\config
ES_JAVA_HOME   C:\elasticsearch-7.16.2\jdk

Important: ES_PATH_HOME should be created and exist along with the JAVA_HOME path that in my case was the next:

JAVA_HOME     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1